# how to check whether activecell is A1 or not in excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel Macros. I have been trying to find whether the active cell is A1 or not. I tried

```
if Activecell.Address = A1 then
      Msgbox(.....)
```

I also tried

```
if Activecell.Name = A1 then
      Msgbox(.....)
```

These two were not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arun, What you have done is not wrong. Your code needs to be changed a bit.

Check this code:

```
If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
    MsgBox "You Selected Cell A1."
End If
```

Comment: @arunp: When you are using .Address then actually you are comparing with absolute cell reference. Check this link: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/15

Comment: @arunp: If you got your solution, please select this as answer and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `Address` is a string. In the example you've shown `A1` is a variable of some type. Strings get wrapped in quotes.

```
If ActiveCell.Address = "A1" Then
```

But I believe address returns an absolute reference, so

```
If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
```

---

Now, you probably could have worked this out yourself if you had done a few things.

1. Use `Option Explicit` in all of your code modules. It forces you to declare your variables, which would have alerted you to the first issue.
2. On the menu bar, go to View >> Immediate. Make sure you have a workbook open and a cell selected, then type the following into the Immediate Window.

   ```
   ?ActiveCell.Address
   ```

   Then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: Oh yeah..! Thank u so much for ur explanation. It helped me to understand these basic things.